# How to get individual chars from user until he puts '.' or enter

Tags: c++

I am looking for help with my task, i need get character string from user until he push '.' or enter? I have no idea how to get  individual char using cin or even getch()? Please guys help me !

Comment: `c++` and `java` are not the same thing.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site to get direct coding help from others. You could find the help of HOW to Write code from other tutorials / sites. OR post your trial code here, if you get any errors, you are unable to solve.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `std::cin.get()` to get a single char.

```
std::vector<char> input;
for(bool key = false; !key;)
{
    char keyPressed = std::cin.get();
    switch(keyPressed)
    {
        case '.':
        case '\n':
            key = true;
            break;
        default:
            input.append(keyPressed);
            break;
    }
}
```

Using a switch statement like above, we can sort out periods and newlines from the rest, making the loop exit when we hit one.